# Variable not working with SPServices

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I'm having an issue with my variable. I'm not sure if it is syntax related, but for some reason the first part of my `if` statement with my variable will not work.

I tested it without the `SPServices` and if I just do that function without `SPServices` it works. I also tested `SPServices` with alerts and not the variable, and those work fine too. Please see code below, any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdown = $("select[title='Item-Status']");
    $().SPServices({ 
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {             
            if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='CCB Team']").length == 0) {
                dropdown.find("option[value='QA Review']").remove();  
            } else if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='QA Team']").length == 1) { 
                alert("You should see this");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind. i realized i was declaring the variable outside of the function i wanted to use it under.  code should be written as so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $().SPServices({ 
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            var dropdown = $("select[title='Item-Status']");
            if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='CCB Team']").length == 0) {
                dropdown.find("option[value='QA Review']").remove();  
            } else if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='QA Team']").length == 1) { 
                alert("You should see this");
            }
        }
    });
});
```